# npm build is still running for production

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angularfire2, angular6

I recently upgraded all my dependency node modules and then started facing this issue.

Ran the below command to build the app for production.

```
npm run ionic:build --prod
```

and then it did not end at all after below output.

```
I:\xxxx>npm run ionic:build --prod
> xxxx@0.0.1 ionic:build I:\xxxxx
> ionic-app-scripts build
[00:25:20]  ionic-app-scripts 3.1.7-201801172029
[00:25:20]  build prod started ...
[00:25:20]  clean started ...
[00:25:20]  clean finished in less than 1 ms
[00:25:20]  copy started ...
[00:25:20]  deeplinks started ...
[00:25:21]  deeplinks finished in 110 ms
[00:25:21]  ngc started ...
[00:25:39]  ngc finished in 18.99 s
[00:25:39]  preprocess started ...
[00:25:39]  preprocess finished in less than 1 ms
[00:25:39]  webpack started ...
[00:25:40]  copy finished in 19.96 s
```

Below is my package.json.

```
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.5",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/tsc-wrapped": "^4.4.6",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.3.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "@types/google-maps": "^3.2.0",
    "animate.css": "^3.6.1",
    "firebase": "^5.0.4",
    "ionic-angular": "3.8.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@firebase/app-types": "^0.3.2",
    "@firebase/auth-types": "^0.3.3",
    "@firebase/database-types": "^0.3.2",
    "@firebase/firestore-types": "^0.4.3",
    "@firebase/messaging-types": "^0.2.3",
    "@firebase/storage-types": "^0.2.3",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.1.7-201801172029",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.9",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2",
    "webpack": "^4.10.2"
  },
```

Please advise what needs to tweak to build quickly as it is supposed to.

Comment: Wait. Sometimes it needs more than 30min depends on the scale of your project.

Comment: Ok, but I kept whole night i.e. almost 8 hours and no luck.

Comment: Can you check your RAM? Sometimes Node.js reaches the maximum. Maybe that is causing a problem. Check the RAM after 10min of operation